# pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra

I have tried running the following simple code;

````
```{r sample}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# LaTeX Table
knitr::kable(dt,format = 'latex')%>%
  column_spec(column = 1,width = '10cm',bold = T)
```
````

This runs fines with the `Knit` button. but get the following error when using `rmarkdown::render()`;

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.173 \centering\rowcolors

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS tst.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output tst.pdf --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
```

Also note that without the `format = 'latex'` option it works fine with `rmarkdown::render()`

I tried the suggestions for similar errors but non of them worked (update Rmarkdown, install MikTex and the pdflatex.exe to path variable). Can someone please help me with this.Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure...have you installed the TeX package `array`?

Comment: I have installed MikTex 2.9

Comment: Have you tried to install the "complete" miktex through its net installer?

Comment: I tried both installing from the website and installr on R

Comment: @Shana I mean on the website, it provides either a "basic" version (200mb ~ish) which comes with most common latex packages, or a Net installer, which they say you should pick when you want to install all latex packages.

Comment: @Hao yes I did download the 191mb from the website. When I use the rmarkdown button Knit button it produces the Pdf well but with the `rmarkdown::render()` only I am getting this error. And also it works fine without `,format = "latex"`

Comment: @Shana I was suggesting you should have installed the other one. The "Net installer", which is a very small exe which will spend a long time and download all the packages.

Comment: @Shana The reason why it works without `format = "latex"` is that `kableExtra` won't do any thing when the format is "markdown" but send out a warning message

Answer (score 0):

Calling the array package in the YAML worked for me.

header-includes:
- \usepackage{array}